# How do I access the console of the website that I want to extract data from?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Sorry for the confusing title. I am a beginner in JavaScript and would like to build this little project to increase my skill level: an image extractor. The user is able to input the website name into the form input. Press Extract and the links of all images show up.

Question: how do I access the website DOM that was entered into the input field?

Comment: I believe the topic you're likely going to want to dig through is called *scraping*.

Comment: The Same Origin Policy makes this impossible with client-side JavaScript

Comment: @Quentin, so I would only be able to do this with server-side such as NodeJS?

Comment: @ZeWorks you can have your website call an endpoint that you set up (you can use any server-side framework/language for this, such as Node, Django, Go, etc). That endpoint (for example, yourdomain.com/scrape/{target_url}) will then do the scraping on the server and send you its findings

Comment: @BrunoEly - thanks for clarifying. Sorry if this sounds stupid, but what exactly is an endpoint? As far as I am aware it's something to do with an API, I never got around understanding the whole concept and how everything relates to each other with an API, database, server etc.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Quentin in the comments, browsers enforce restrictions on cross-domain requests like this. The [Same Origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) will prevent your site from pulling the HTML source of a page on a different domain.

Since this is a learning exercise, I'd recommend picking another task that doesn't get into the weeds of cross-origin request security issues. Alternatively, you could implement a "scraper" like this out of the browser using Node (JavaScript), Python, PHP, Ruby, or many other scripting languages.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this if you already have the html content:

```
var html = document.createElement('html');
html.innerHTML = "<html><body><div><img src='image-url.png'></div></body></html>";
console.log(html.querySelector("img").src);
```

If you also need to get the content via ajax calls, I would suggest doing your entire code server side, using something like [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)